# How to use ob_get_contents with a function with arguments

Tags: php, ob-get-contents

I have a function like this:

```
function show_aval($place) {
//some function
}
```

I want to translate this into a variable so I do this:

```
ob_start();
show_aval(london);
$avalrooms = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
```

This will be fine if the argument is always "london" which is not. It may change to York or Manchester, etc. My question is what can I do in order to indicate the argument through the variable like this: `$avalrooms["london"]`, `$avalrooms["york"]`, `$avalrooms["liverpool"]`, etc. without having to declare each variable one by one.

EDIT:

the code below:

```
ob_start();
show_aval(london);
$show_aval = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

ob_start();
show_aval(york);
$show_aval2 = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

ob_start();
show_aval(liverpool);
$show_aval3 = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
```

will work but its just too much code. I tried with foreach but that seems to get ob_get_contents nullified.

Comment: Set `$place` somewhere before your ob_* code then do `show_aval($place);`,  though why can't `show_aval` be changed to return rather then echo, or why cant the ob_code go inside that function?

Comment: This is a Undefined Constant, warning or notice (depending on your version of PHP).  PHP assumes you mean `"london"` (as a string) but you should use a variable or quotes: [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/73c188e7e12dfe5f978d0dece300a8be61d85bde).  You can also just use `$avalrooms = ob_get_clean();` instead of `$avalrooms = ob_get_contents();` and `ob_clean();`

Comment: because the code executes as I declare the variable without the ob_code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the cities in an array, loop over the array, and use them as the function argument and array index.

```
$avalrooms = [];
$cities = ["london", "york", "liverpool"];
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    ob_start();
    show_aval($city);
    $avalrooms[$city] = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();
}
```

Comment: something is odd. Seems like ob_get_contents(); is not working because the code appears at the beginning of the page which means its being executed as the variable is being declared.

Comment: I forgot the parentheses after `ob_clean`. Try it now.